# Is escaped hyphen equal to unescaped hyphen?

Tags: java, regex

using java regular expression , and I found the following example

```
Print\\-Services
```

I am wondering why `\\-`, does it escape the -?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape a '-' in a regex.  It is only a meta-character inside a `[...]` character class specification.

If that was a Java String literal, then the first `'\'` would escape the 2nd `'\'` and that would give `\-` in the regex ... which is nonsense<sup>1</sup>.

If that was NOT a String literal, then the first `'\'` is escaping the 2nd `'\'` in the regex.  That is NOT nonsense.  It means match a backslash character.

---

<sup>1 - It is, however, *legal* nonsense.  The javadoc says: *"A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct."*  The redundant backslash would be ignored.</sup>

Comment: I wouldn't say it is non-sense. It is just redundant syntax.

Comment: @nhahtdh - you are free to write your own Answer that says that :-)

Comment: Nah, I think it is a bit overkill for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are referring to the String literal which would be written out as `"Print\\-Services"` in a Java program.  In that case, the regular expression would contain an escaped '-' character, which doesn't really make sense, but is apparently not treated as erroneous by java.util.regex.Pattern.  From the javadoc:

> A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless
>   of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct.

As an example:

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("Print\\-Services");     
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("Print-Services"); // No PatternSyntaxException   
// Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("Print\-Services"); // Not valid Java syntax
```

I didn't test really thoroughly, but it appears that Pattern is ignoring the escape character.

```
System.out.println( pattern1.matcher("Print-Services").matches() ); // true  
System.out.println( pattern2.matcher("Print-Services").matches() ); // true
```

It seems like whoever supplied that example was giving an example which was either confusing or confused.