# Why do ";" and "\\;" find the same?

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I just found Java code like this:

```
"bla;bla;bla".split("\\;");
```

It returns:

```
["bla","bla","bla"]   // String array of course
```

String.split does use regex, but from my research I found that `;` is not a special character in regex and doesn't have to be escaped. So I tried replacing it with:

```
"bla;bla;bla;".split(";");
```

and it still does the same! So what is happening here? Is Java trying to be nice and ignores a useless backslash in the regex? But I tried it with Notepad++, too, and there it also both finds a single semikolon.

Comment: It's just how regex interpreter works. But your guess is correct

Comment: "Is Java trying to be nice and ignores a useless backslash in the regex?" yes, sometimes developers like to copy-paste regex from different flavours where some characters may require escaping (like `/` in JavaScript where regex is used in form `/regex/flags`) so it is nice to let regex engine ignore unnecessary escaping.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247454/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hm, maybe. The answers are pretty similar, but I find Andy Turner's answer more clear than Matt Rick's answer and especially more useful than Stephen C's answer, which insults the poor regex. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Javadoc of `Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (emphasis mine):

> The backslash character ('\') serves to introduce escaped constructs
>
> ...
>
> It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language. **A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct.**

Comment: Andy, can you explain [this](http://rextester.com/WVXD19525), and why it seems that splitting on `\a` does not throw an error, contrary to the docs above?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's splitting on "The alert (bell) character ('\u0007')".

Answer (score 3):

In the following code:

```
"bla;bla;bla".split("\\;");
```

`String#split()` executes in a regex context.  Two backslashes `\\` result in a literal backslash, and so you end up splitting on `\;`, which functionally is the same as just splitting on `;`, because semicolon does not need to be escaped.

If you tried the following split, you would not the result you expect:

```
"bla;bla;bla".split("\\\\;");
```

This would correspond, in regex terms, to splitting on literal `\;`.  Since that separator never appears in your string, you would just get an array whose first element is that input string.

See the answer by @AndyTurner for an explanation on why splitting on `\;` is allowed in the first place.

Comment: I think that your "which functionally is the same" comment would benefit from the documentation linked in my answer. Feel free to grab it, and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner Interesting +1.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are fine. However, nobody mentioned [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)

Java does not have a raw or literal string (e.g. like a `@"...";` verbatim string in C# or a `r"..."` raw string in Python). Nonetheless, for regular expressions we have the `quote` method that returns a literal pattern String for the specified String:

> This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern
>   that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.

So, if you would have used `quote` to specify your pattern, no split would have happened as illustrated in the following code sample:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Example
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
  String sourcestring = "bla;bla;bla";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("\\;"));
  String[] parts = re.split(sourcestring);
    for(int partsIdx = 0; partsIdx < parts.length; partsIdx++ ){
      System.out.println( "[" + partsIdx + "] = " + parts[partsIdx]);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[0] = bla;bla;bla
```

Otherwise, it's just an escaped semi-colon in the regex context of the `split` method as explained by Tim and Andy.